# Parse and Keychainwrapper

Tags: ios, iphone, security

I'm creating my first app and I'm attempting to make a secure sign up / login.  I've read a couple articles and tutorials stating that KeyChain is the best way to secure a users credentials on an iOS app.  I'm also using parse to store my user data, which has its own secure sign up and login procedure.  Should I do both keychain and parse for security or pick one?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not an either/or situation. I think the deciding factor of whether to use the keychain is whether or not you need to store any sensitive information (credentials) on the device. This is independent of what happens with a server.

Comment: What would be the proper?  Is it expected for an app to store the users name and password on the keychain and server?

Comment: If it's credentials for your server, then the keychain is a great place to store them. If it's something you expect the user to type in (say, on a login screen) then maybe they shouldn't be stored on the device at all. If you only want to store a user's id, you might consider NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I guess I should ask:  When would I want to store credentials in keychain versus the server?  The end result is the same for the user: logging in and signing up.

Comment: If the credentials are for getting to the server, then they can't be on the server because then your device wouldn't be able to get to the server. That's when they would need to be on the device (and where the keychain would make sense).

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that apps like instagram, facebook, and twitter store the users password on the device, so users can then login to access the server?

Comment: I'm sure that some of your examples probably do store some server credentials on the device (and hopefully in the keychain).